# How should I use the word “Hope”

Tags: word-usage

Should I add the word “will”before “turns”?.How about “could”?Eg:Jasper hopes she turns the car owner and their cars into stones.

Comment: You hope that someone will do something, but both _that_ and _will_ can be omitted in casual speech - "Hope you have a good holiday!"

Comment: Thanks a lot...lol

Comment: Your example sentence is a strange construction but it is grammatical. The way you use “hopes” is correct and you can use it like that both in ordinary speech and in ordinary written English (like a fantasy story).  The changes you propose are possible too, with each altering the meaning slightly with the *modal verbs* “will” and “could”. Notice the main verb “turns” changes to “turn” with the addition of the modal verbs: “...hopes she will turn...”, “...hopes she could turn...”